# powershellによるGUIで、sleep中に終了できない。

Tags: powershell

powershellで、

概略ですが、

```
function func1{
   for ($i = 0;$i -lt 10;$i++){
       Write-Host $i
       start-sleep 1
   }
}
$form.Add_Shown({func1})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

このようにしています。
forループによる処理中に、ウィンドウの右上の×ボタンや、Ctrl+Cが効きません。
どうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

使われている`$form`はおそらく[System.Windows.Forms.Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)でしょうから、まずWindowメッセージ処理を行うことと、想定する事象用のイベントハンドラを用意して登録する必要があるでしょう。

- WriteとSleepだけのループではWindowメッセージ処理が行われないので、ループの中に[DoEvents()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)を追加する
  (ただし[Application.DoEvents メソッドを使うべきでない理由](https://blog.jhashimoto.net/entry/20111113/1321133064)といった記事もあるので他の手段を探すのでも良いでしょう)
- Ctrl+C を検出し、対応する処理を行うために、[KeyDown イベント](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)のハンドラを定義・登録し、ハンドラ内では押されたキー種別をチェックしてCtrl+Cなら中断・終了処理をする
- 閉じる(`X`)ボタンクリックを検出し、対応する処理を行うために、[Closing イベント](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)のハンドラを定義・登録し、中断・終了処理をする
- `for`のループを終了させるための判定や手段が無いので、判定用フラグ変数を定義・初期化し、上記ハンドラにて設定を行う。`for`ループの中で判定してフラグが設定されていたらループを終了する
  [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2)

以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$script:Cancel = $false  #### 中断・終了判定用フラグ変数

#### 閉じるボタン等Closingイベントハンドラ定義・登録
$Close = {
    $form.Visible = $False
    $script:Cancel = $True
}
$form.Add_Closing($Close)

#### Ctrl+Cキー判定用KeyDownイベントハンドラ定義・登録
$KDown = {
    if (($_.KeyCode -eq "C") -And $_.Control)
    {
        $form.Visible = $False
        $script:Cancel = $True
    }
}
$form.Add_KeyDown($KDown)

#### 質問からのコピーおよび対策追加
function func1{
   for ($i = 0;$i -lt 10;$i++){
       Write-Host $i
       [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()  #### Windowメッセージ処理
       if ($script:Cancel) {  #### 中断・終了判定とループ終了
           break
       }
       start-sleep 1
   }
}
$form.Add_Shown({func1})
$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。実際に動かしたところ、質問通りの動作を確認いたいました。ただ、当初の質問が説明不足で申し訳ないのですが、実際には「1秒～80秒で終わる処理を行い、その後、60秒待機し、また処理を行う」というループになっています。提示いただきましたコードですと、1秒間隔での判定になっているため、×ボタンを押すと1秒以内に閉じられますが、start-sleep 60にすると、閉じるまで数十秒待たなければならなくなってします。また、Ctrl+Cというのは、powershellコンソール上のCtrl+Cのことです。説明不足で申し訳ございません。色々なサイトで調べましたが、現状、ウィンドウの移動なども、スムーズに行かないので、GUIで固まらないような動作になるようにするには、マルチスレッドにするしか無いのでしょうか？環境はpowershell 5.1しか使えない環境です。

Comment: @bew3g3hjjj さん、それはそもそもダイアログフォームのメインに登録したループで実行するのではなく、タイマーを時間調整して使うのが良いのでは？ そうすればSleepを使う必要は無いでしょう。それから質問に提示するソースコードや情報は、問題や要望を的確にとらえたものにしてください。書かれていないことを後出しされると、回答内容が適切でなくなり、双方の時間の無駄になります。あまりに条件等が変わるようならいったんこの質問はここで終了して、新しい質問を立ててみてください。